# What Progress 4GL parameters could affect default frame width?

Tags: parameters, progress-4gl, codepages

While upgrading an application from Progress 4GL 7.4 to 10.2b ABL a problem has arisen in the menu display, for which I have no source code.  Instead of showing 2 columns of menu choices I am seeing 3 columns with only two visible at a time (the left pair by default) ...
1  option          51 option        2  option 
52 option          3  option        53 option 
4  option 
as if the menu had been assembled as one long string designed for 2 columns in an 80 character boxed frame, and is now being displayed in a 120 character frame, still boxed as if it were 80 characters wide, changing it into 3 columns only 2 of which are visible.

Since I cannot see or directly affect the code for displaying the menu, I would like to find out if there are any parameters that might be used to control the the default frame size for terminal display and that could have altered between versions 7.4 and 10.2b, or that may have been overlooked during upgrade/install.

Answer (score 1):

The main culprit is probably either your TERM variable or your protermcap file.

TERM needs to point to a protermcap entry that is as wide as you need the frame to be.

Almost all of the default entries are 80 columns wide.

If you have kept all the scripts the same and all you did was switch Progress versions then my guess is that someone modified the protermcap in your old installation.  You would need to bring those modifications forward.

I would first make a copy of $DLC/protermcap in your 10.2B environment.  Just to be safe.

Then get a copy of the old protermcap from your old v7 installation.  Put it somewhere other than $DLC -- such as /home/test/protermcap.

Then you can set the PROTERMCAP environment variable:

```
PROTERMCAP=/home/test/protermcap
export PROTERMCAP
```

Now start your application.  If it works as expected then you can either copy that protermcap into $DLC (and try to remember all of this the next time you upgrade...) or put the v7 protermcap someplace safe and modify your scripts to use the PROTERMCAP environment variable.

It is also possible that Progress changed the underlying protermcap -- 7.x was a *long* time ago and, as I recall, one of the things that has changed in the intervening years is the addition of the "ws" attribute in some terminal definitions (notably xterm) which allow a single definition to fit itself to whatever size the window happens to be when Progress is started.  Back in the bad old days you would have defined a static width of 80 (or 132) chars and regardless of what the actual width was Progress would use that.  More modern releases are flexible -- but that could cause your problem.  Same cure, put the old protermcap back in place.  Or use a terminal window of the expected size.